# Stubbing `session_id` in Rails Integration Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing, sessionid, webmock

I have a question about Rails Integration Tests.
I have this app that talks to this other internal app.

The app makes a request to internal_app, and one of the params for that request involves the session_id, stored in the session cookie.
For a variety of reasons, requests to external services are stubbed out using `webmock` and `vcr` gems. This records the request/response to a fixture file, so that the next time the request is run, it hits the fixture file instead of the real service.

My issue, is that the `session_id` changes each time the test is run. This means that, according to webmock, the request made does not match the request stubbed, which leads to a failed test. In controller tests, I can access the session directly, and change/stub whatever I want in there as desired. With integration tests, I cannot access the session directly, and so I am stuck using whatever session_id Rails generates for the test. Does anyone know of a good way to modify/stub the session_id for integration tests, to something expected? There are some less preferred ways I am considering (involving ditching the vcr gem for those integration tests for example), but I would prefer to find a way to have session_id be some expected value instead.

Tests are made with Capybara/Poltergeist/phantomjs, on a Rails 5.1 application.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be stubbing internals of your app during integration tests since it really defeats the point of integration tests.  You can however configure VCR to ignore the session_id using the `:match_requests_on` option - https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/docs/request-matching - when matching the request and then use dynamic cassettes - https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/3-0-3/docs/cassettes/dynamic-erb-cassettes - to insert the correct session_id into the response if necessary

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try it out.

I'm curious, how would you approach the stubbing/not stubbing issue?
The integration test still hits the controller, and the controller still executes the code that tries to make the request to an external service. In this case, I would think that external service request should still be stubbed?